# If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers such that $a^{2015}+b^{2015}=2015$, find the maximum value of $a+b$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, holder-inequality

**Hint:** Just use the power mean inequality
$$\left(\frac{a^{2015}+b^{2015}}{2}\right)^{1/2015}\geq\frac{a+b}{2}$$

### My Attempt

I was unable to figure out the solution, using the power mean inequality, but I went ahead and used Bergström's inequality. The given condition is
$$\frac{a^{2015}}{1^{2014}}+\frac{b^{2015}}{1^{2014}}=2015$$
Using a generalised form of the inequality, we get
\begin{align*}
2015&\geq\frac{[a+b]^{2015}}{[1+1]^{2014}}\\
(2)^{2014/2015}(2015)^{1/2015)}&\geq a+b\\
2.006&\geq a+b\\
\end{align*}
I plugged in the $2.006$ value and it worked. However, I'd like to use Hölder's inequality or the hint to solve this. Would you have any tips?

Comment: What does the power mean inequality $\left(\frac{a^{2015}+b^{2015}}{2}\right)^{1/2015}\geq\frac{a+b}{2}$ tell you about $a+b$ if $a^{2015}+b^{2015}=2015$ ?

Comment: Use Lagrange multiplier theorem, and you'll get:
$L(a,b,\lambda)=f(a,b)-\lambda(a^{2015}-b^{2015}-2015)=\\ =a+b-\lambda(a^{2015}+b^{2015}-2015).$
$L^{'}(a,b,\lambda)_a=0=1-2015\cdot \lambda \cdot a^{2014}\\
L^{'}(a,b,\lambda)_b=0=1-2015\cdot\lambda\cdot b^{2014}\\
L^{'}(a,b,\lambda)_\lambda=0=0-(a^{2015}+b^{2015}-2015)$ From here you need to find those $(a,b)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the given hint:
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{a^{2015}+b^{2015}}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2015}} &\geq \frac{a+b}{2} \\
2 \cdot \left(\frac{2015}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2015}} &\geq a+b \quad (\because a^{2015}+b^{2015}=2015) \\
a+b &\leq 2.0068
\end{align*}

Comment: Wait, it was really that simple? This is what I thought at first too, but figured I must be interpreting the question wrong 

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is a proof of the inequality via Hölder’s inequality as OP asked for one:

First, note $\frac{1}{2015}+\frac{2014}{2015}=\frac{1}{2015}+\frac{1}{\frac{2015}{2014}}=1$. Then, by Hölder,

\begin{align*}
a\cdot1+b\cdot1&\le\left(a^{2015}+b^{2015}\right)^{\frac{1}{2015}}\left(1^ {\frac{2015}{2014}}+1^{\frac{2015}{2014}}\right)^{\frac{2014}{2015}}\\
a+b&\leq2015^{\frac{1}{2015}}\cdot 2^{\frac{2014}{2015}}\approx2.006
\end{align*}

Of course, using the Power Mean inequality would be more direct and simple.

Answer (score 1):

For constrained optimization problem, you look at the stationary points and boundary points. The target function is $F(a,b) = a + b$, the constraint function is $G(a,b) = a^{2015} + b^{2015} - 2015 = 0$ and the boundary is that for the region $a > 0$ and $b > 0$.

The stationary points are where $dF = 0$ and $dG = 0$:
$$dF = da + db = 0, \quad dG = 2015 \left(a^{2014} da + b^{2014} db\right) = 0.$$
Substituting for $db$ from the first into the second yields
$$2015 \left(a^{2014} - b^{2014}\right) da = 0,$$
thus
$$a^{2014} = b^{2014},$$
from which follows
$$a = b.$$
Substituting into $G(a,b) = 0$ yields
$$a^{2015} = \frac{2015}{2} = b^{2015}\quad→\quad a = \left(\frac{2015}{2}\right)^{1/2015} = b\quad→\quad a + b = 2\left(\frac{2015}{2}\right)^{1/2015}.$$
For the boundary,
$$a = 0\quad→\quad b = 2015^{1/2015}\quad→\quad a + b = 2015^{1/2015},$$
and
$$b = 0\quad→\quad a = 2015^{1/2015}\quad→\quad a + b = 2015^{1/2015}.$$

The boundary would actually be excluded by the problem statement, so if either of these were larger than the value of $F(a,b) = a + b$ at the stationary point (they're not), then there'd be no maximum, only a supremum. Instead, they're both smaller and equal to each other, so that means there's no minimum, but only an infinimum - $2015^{1/2015}$ - and the stationary point value
$$2\left(\frac{2015}{2}\right)^{1/2015}$$
is the maximum.

The hint is not needed.

Comment: OP asked for a solution that used power mean, and Lagrangian is very overkill for something as simple as this.

Comment: This looks like an application of [Convex Optimization/Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) ... and came out to be almost as simple as a [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. I have non-linear optimization, including convex optimization, in my version of [AlgLib C++](https://github.com/LydiaMarieWilliamson/ALGLIB_cpp), though the methods of convex programming are not directly implemented.